# delete duplicates method wont delete duplicates

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I have written a method that executes a query that deletes duplicates in a MS Access file.  The query works properly when run in MS Access but nothing happens when it is run through java. Other querys work using this same connection string. Can another set of eyes see what is causing this to happen?

```
public static void delete_duplicates() throws Exception{

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String sDBQ = "C:/AW.mdb";

    String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + sDBQ + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","");;
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String query = "DELETE "+
                    "FROM AW " +
                    "WHERE id not in (select min(id) from AW group by Symbol, Direction, START_DT, END_DT)";

    System.out.println(query);

    stmt.executeUpdate(query);

    stmt.close();
}
```

Comment: why this READONLY=true in database string? I would try by removing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are connecting like this:

`String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + sDBQ + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";`

You have an attribute `READONLY` set to `true`, so you cannot make modifications to your database.